# Is it not possible to get altitude from MKUserLocation in IOS MKMapKit?

Tags: mkmapview, mapkit, cllocationmanager, mkmapviewdelegate

Is it possible to get altitude from MKUserLocation in IOS MKMapKit?

Specifically I'm trying to get altitude within the MKMapViewDelegate's callback "didUpdateUserLocation" which provides an MKUserLocation object?

If not should I really be using CLLocationManager with it's startUpdatingLocation() method to capture location & altitude changes and scrap the use of mapview's MKMapViewDelegate's callback "didUpdateUserLocation"???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

missed it:

> MKUserLocation.location.altitude property